# How would I copy the gallery, posts & pages from a compromised wordpress install to a fresh one?

Tags: wordpress, backup, disaster-recovery

A Wordpress install on one of my servers has been compromised.  What's the quickest way to export the gallery, posts and pages in a manner that won't export any back doors along with them?  Then how do I import those into the fresh Wordpress installation?

I want to avoid copying any php files as the attacker may have left a back door.  I also want to avoid copying the entire database because the attacker may have left a back door in there, too.

Comment: Restore from backup then update Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress built-in export (WordPress eXtended RSS or WXR) would contain your posts, pages, comments, custom fields, categories, and tags. Images can be donloaded from the old location (must be live) to the new one; be sure to check the "Download and import file attachments" box on import.

If there are galleries managed/created by some plugin then you'd have to have a more detailed look at the particular plugin used.